WP CF7 how to change calendar color
I would like to change the colors in the calendar displayed in CF7 using [date]. By default, the selected day and the set, cancel, clear and header fields in the mobile version are blue. I can't find the *.css class responsible for these colors? How can I change these colors to make them friendly to my website?
I tried changing the colors in the CF7 css plugin styles

This appears to be using a native <input type="date">, and with that you don't get that level of control. The datepicker is rendered by the browser.

You can add your date field as hidden and using flatpickr or any other js library to create your own field and update date in that hidden field.
